# Rails 4 Param Not Found Show Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a blog platform and am working on getting my comments functionality to work. It was working but all of a sudden stopped and started throwing this error. I have a comment form in my articles show page ActionController::ParameterMissing in CommentsController#create 
Param not found: comments

Here is the code:

## comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Your comment has been saved!"
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to(@comment.post)
end

private
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :comment)
end
end
```

### articles show.html.erb

below is my comment form

```
<div class="container com_form">
<h4>Add a Comment</h4>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <b><%= f.label :commenter %></b>
  <p><%= f.text_field :commenter %></p>

  <b><%= f.label :comment %></b>
  <p><%= f.text_area :comment %></p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

### Application Trace

```
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:19:in `comment_params'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:5:in `create
```

I am not sure why all of a sudden it's populating this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

### routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }

resources :users

resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end

root 'pages#index'
get 'users/sign_in' => 'users/sessions#create'
post 'users/sign_in' => 'users/sessions#create'
post '/articles/:article_id/' => 'comments#create'
post 'articles/new' => 'articles#create'
get 'articles/:id' => 'articles#show'
patch 'articles/:id' => 'articles#update'
get 'atricles/:id/edit' => 'articles#edit'
delete '/articles/:id' => 'articles#destroy'
get 'users/:username' => 'users#show'
```

**Link to Error Screenshot**

[Error Screenshot](https://sjconfections.tinytake.com/sf/MjEzMzg0XzEzMzU1NTE)

**Link to repo on GitHub**

[Blog Repo](https://github.com/sweetjava12/Blogster)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there is no comment information in sent params.
I'm not sure, but try changing @article.comments.build to Comment.new(author_id: @article.id) in article's show view.

Comment: Here are the commetns

Parameters:
{"authenticity_token"=>"RJuVTTR4v+BRU2337EnziAzJ/5ouxdq7sURbL+vwik0=",
 "article_id"=>"1"}

Comment: Per Jakub I made the change to the article's show view and I'm still getting the same error: param not fount: comment. It appears comment is not being passed in the parameters still.

Comment: Would you be so kind and also include routes.rb + screenshot of error page? Your problem is very strange, so every information is important.

Answer (score 0):

In the line : `<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>`, try changing it to just `Comment.new`.

You are handling the Active Record association in the controller here:

`@comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)`

#### Update:

Change your form to look like this:

```
<%= form_for([@article, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
  <b><%= f.label :commenter %></b>
  <p><%= f.text_field :commenter %></p>

  <b><%= f.label :comment %></b>
  <p><%= f.text_area :comment %></p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
```

Alternatively, since you are defining `@comment = Comment.new` in your show controller action, you could use:

`form_for([@article, @comment])`

Comment: I did what you suggested and it's still populating the same error. It's weird how it won't even allow the show view because of comment create/comment_params issue

Comment: Can you post a link to your repository?

Comment: when you say the "show" view, do you mean the article show view? My suspicion is that your Comment model is not set up correctly.  Can you post your Comment class and Article class?

Comment: Yes, when I try to view an individual article, that's when the error populates.

Comment: I got it working on my computer. I edited my answer to show you how I did it.